# derivatives of hyperbolic functions

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

I have seen it proven directly using the $\frac{d}{dx}$ operator and making use of the exponentials, i.e $\frac{d}{dx} $ $\ sinh x $= $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{e^{x} +e^{-x}}{2} $

I was wondering if I could use the limits, I tried with $\ sinhx$ and reached the final form of :

$h\overset{lim}{\rightarrow} 0 \frac{e^{x}}{2} \frac{e^{h}-1}{h} + \frac{e^{-x}}{2} \frac{1- e^{-h}}{h}$ 
which I felt was a dead end. 
can it be evaluated, and if so, with steps.

Comment: You are aware of the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1$? This you can prove either by expanding $e^h$ or using L'Hopital. Then, you are done, right?

Comment: now that you've pointed L hopital I do. what do you mean by "expanding $\ e^{h} $ " ?

Comment: There is a Taylor series for $e^h$, given by $e^h = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{h^n}{n!}$ that converges uniformly for all $h$. You can substitute the partial sums in place of $e^h$, then you will get a better idea of why the limit is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\sinh(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\right)=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{e^{x+h}+e^{-(x+h)}}{2}-\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}}{h}$$ $$=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^x}{2}\dfrac{\left(e^h-1\right)}{h}+\dfrac{e^{-x}}{2}\dfrac{\left(e^{-h}-1\right)}{h}$$
These limits are very well-known, but if you must, you could use L'Hopital's Rule or Taylor Series or other methods to see that $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\left(e^h-1\right)}{h}=1$$
and $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\left(e^{-h}-1\right)}{h}=-1$$
so that $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^x}{2}\dfrac{\left(e^h-1\right)}{h}+\dfrac{e^{-x}}{2}\dfrac{\left(e^{-h}-1\right)}{h}=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=\cosh(x)$$